# ¿como podría encontrar el objeto persona a través de su dni?

Tags: java

Esta clase es el main aquí

Se han declarado los objetos

Lo que quiero es obtener es la persona (con sus atributos) a través del DNI, no se como aplicar el método `indexof()` para obtener el posición de la persona

```
import java.util.*;

public class lista_5 {

public static void main (String [] args) {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String datoDni;
    int opcion, indice;
    LinkedList<Persona> lista_persona = new LinkedList<Persona>();  
    //aqui se han declarado los objetos personas
    Persona p1 = new Persona("50394830a", "pol", "pol", "mas", 50, 80);
    Persona p2 = new Persona("96148620g", "jona", "bach", "fem", 15, 100);
    Persona p3= new Persona("82364952g", "aczel", "pol", "mas", 50, 60);
    Persona p4 = new Persona("0367516s", "ahn", "ian", "mas", 20, 80);  
    //aqui se han añadido los objetos personas a la linkedlist
    lista_persona.add(p1);
    lista_persona.add(p2);
    lista_persona.add(p3);
    lista_persona.add(p4);
    for (Persona per:lista_persona) {
        System.out.println(per.toString());
    }       
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("hecho");

    //se ha creado un metodo para eliminar un dni   
        Iterator<Persona> it = lista_persona.iterator();                
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            String dniEliminado=it.next().getDni();             
            if(dniEliminado.equals("0367516s")) {
                it.remove();
            }
        }   
}
}
// aqui esta la clse persona con sus atributos
public class Persona {

String dni, nombre, apellido, sexo;

int edad, peso;

public Persona(String dni, String nombre, String apellido, String sexo, int edad, int peso) {
    this.dni = dni;
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.apellido = apellido;
    this.sexo = sexo;
    this.edad = edad;
    this.peso = peso;
}
public String getDni() {
    return dni;
}
public String toString() {
    return "Persona [dn,lmlklknli=" + dni + ", nombre=" + nombre + ", apellido=" + apellido + ", sexo=" + sexo + ", edad="+ edad + ", peso=" + peso + "]";
}
}
```

En clase hemos empezado con el tema de las listas dinámicas de java.

Comment: Estás ya encontrando a una persona por su DNI para eliminarla de la lista, así que no entiendo bien cuál es el problema o la pregunta real que tienes. Sugiero que leas [ask], que edites tu pregunta y que intentes explicarte mejor. Un saludo.

Answer (score 1):

Espero te sea util

```
import java.util.*;

public class solucion {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //Creamos la lista
        List<Persona> lista_persona = new ArrayList<>();

        //Creamos las personas
        Persona p1 = new Persona("50394830a", "pol", "pol", "mas", 50, 80);
        Persona p2 = new Persona("96148620g", "jona", "bach", "fem", 15, 100);
        Persona p3 = new Persona("82364952g", "aczel", "pol", "mas", 50, 60);
        Persona p4 = new Persona("0367516s", "ahn", "ian", "mas", 20, 80);

        //Agregamos las personas a la lista
        lista_persona.add(p1);
        lista_persona.add(p2);
        lista_persona.add(p3);
        lista_persona.add(p4);
        
        //Llamamos al metodo que nos verificala persona
        solucion.obtener_posicion("82364952g", lista_persona);
    }

    public static void obtener_posicion(String dni, List<Persona> lista){

        //Variables que almacenaran la posicion, y la velidez si existe o no la persona
        boolean existe = false;
        int posicion = 0;

        //Bucle que recorre la lista que se le pase por parametro
        for (int i = 0; i < lista.size(); i++) {
            
            //Si la persona existe, almacena la posicion y cambia el valor a true
            if(lista.get(i).obtener_dni().equals(dni)){

                posicion = i + 1;
                existe = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        //Mostramos en que posicion esta la persona
        if(existe){

            System.out.println("\nLa posicion de esa personas en la lista es: "+posicion);
            System.out.println("\nLos datos de la persona son: "+ lista.get(posicion-1).obtener_persona());
        }
        else{

            System.out.println("La persona no esta en la lista");
        }
    }
}


// aqui esta la clse persona con sus atributos
class Persona {

    private String dni, nombre, apellido, sexo;

    private int edad, peso;

    public Persona(String dni, String nombre, String apellido, String sexo, int edad, int peso) {

        this.dni = dni;
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.apellido = apellido;
        this.sexo = sexo;
        this.edad = edad;
        this.peso = peso;
    }

    public String obtener_dni(){

        return dni;
    }

    public String obtener_persona(){

        String mensaje = "\nDNI: "+dni+"\nNombre: "+nombre+"\nApellido: "+apellido+"\nSexo: "+sexo+"\nEdad: "+edad+"\nPeso: "+peso+"\n";
        return mensaje;
    }
}
```

Comment: muchas gracias por tu respuesta, me ah servido de mucho y me gusta mucho todas las comprobaciones que has hecho,  al final tambien llegue a una solucion sin tener que obtener la posicion index     ,                       System.out.println("introdcue el dni");
     datoDni=sc.next();
     for(Persona persona:lista_persona) {
      if(persona.dni.equals(datoDni))
      System.out.println(persona.toString());
     }                                                                                                              que te parece, es un metodo que he incluido en el main directamente

Comment: Ohh muy bien ;)